# PHP Imagick, HEIC format on Windows

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have XAMMP x86, on Windows 7, PHP 7.3.2.

Installed Imagick following instructions: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick

Everything works fine, except HEIC format reading.

I get an error:

`ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat HEIC' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509`

PHPINFO:

```
imagick module | enabled
-- | --
imagick module version | 3.4.4
imagick classes | Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version | ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x86 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version | ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x86 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright | Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date | 2017-11-23
ImageMagick number of supported formats: | 238
ImageMagick supported formats | 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CLIPBOARD, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EMF, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FLIF, FPX, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, GV, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCREENSHOT, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WPG, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

So, the question:

**Is it possible to work with HEIC format on Windows platform?**

**If yes, what I need to do anymore?**

**P.S.** I've read, that needed `libde265` and `libheif` libraries. I thought, that this issue was deciced and these libraries was builded in. As I see, it is not true. If need to install it, tell me, please, where can I find these DLLs?

Comment: You need those libraries and you need a current enough version of ImageMagick. IM 7.0.7.11 is not current enough. See https://imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php. A search of Google (did you do that) shows me https://github.com/ImageMagick/libheif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of ImageMagick that you are using is too old. You will need to upgrade to at least the version below but I would advise you to upgrade to the latest version.

```
2018-02-09  7.0.7-23 Dirk Lemstra <dirk@lem.....org>
  * Add support for reading the HEIC image format to the Windows build.
```